# Nhibernate mapping a class which has a generic list property

Tags: c#, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, generic-list

I am new to Nhibernate and I am trying to map a class (Invoice) which has a generic list property using Nhibernate but I keep getting
error: "An association from the table InvoiceDetails refers to an unmapped class: System.Int32".
Because each invoice has more details I have tought of one to many relation between Invoices and InvoiceDetails table.

Details:
a) Invoice class:

```
public class Invoice
{
    private IList<InvoiceDetail> _invoiceDetails = new List<InvoiceDetail>();

    public virtual int InvoiceID { get; set; }
    public virtual string SerialNumber { get; set; }
    public virtual string Number { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime InvoiceDate { get; set; }
    public virtual decimal Amount { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<InvoiceDetail> InvoiceDetails
    {
        get { return _invoiceDetails; }
        set { _invoiceDetails = value; }
    }
    public virtual Customer customer { get; set; }
    public virtual Institution Institution { get; set; }
    public virtual Receipt receipt { get; set; }
    public virtual bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
}
```

b) InvoiceDetail class:

```
public class InvoiceDetail
{
    public virtual int InvoiceDetailID { get; set; }
    public virtual int InvoiceID { get; set; }
    public virtual string ServiceDescription { get; set; }
    public virtual string Unit { get; set; }
    public virtual int Quantity { get; set; }
    public virtual double Value { get; set; }
    public virtual bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
}
```

c) Invoice mapping file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
    assembly="MyProject" namespace="MyProject.Model">
    <class name="Invoice" table="Invoices">
        <id name="InvoiceID" column="InvoiceID" type="int">
            <generator class="native"></generator>
        </id>
        <property name="SerialNumber" column ="InvoiceSerialNumber"/>
        <property name="Number" column ="InvoiceNumber"/>
        <property name="InvoiceDate"/>
        <property name="Amount"/>
        <property name="IsDeleted" />
        <many-to-one name="Institution" column="InstitutionID" />
        <bag name="InvoiceDetails" access="nosetter.camelcase"
            inverse ="true" lazy ="false" cascade="all-delete-orphan">
            <key column="InvoiceID"/>
            <many-to-one class="MyProject.Model.InvoiceDetail, MyProject"/>
        </bag>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

d) InvoiceDetail mapping file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
    assembly="MyProject" namespace="MyProject.Model">
    <class name="InvoiceDetail" table="InvoiceDetails">
        <id name="InvoiceDetailID" column="InvoiceDetailID" type="int">
            <generator class="native"></generator>
         </id>
         <many-to-one name="InvoiceID" column="InvoiceID" />
         <property name="ServiceDescription"/>
         <property name="Unit"/>
         <property name="Quantity"/>
         <property name="Value"/>
         <property name="IsDeleted" />    
     </class>
 </hibernate-mapping>
```

Comment: your many-to-one InvoiceID seems to be wrong. It should be a property. Or the type of property InvoiceID should be like many-to-one Invoice.Institution : a class. (And the name of the property should be changed to Invoice)

Answer (score 0):

Looks pretty good!

### Fix InvoiceID

You need to fix the `InvoiceDetail.InvoiceID` property.  With many-to-one properties, you should model them as references to the parent entity instead of just as simple value properties containing an ID.  You got it right with `Invoice.Institution`.

In `InvoiceDetail`, replace this...

```
public virtual int InvoiceID { get; set; }
```

... with this:

```
public virtual Invoice Invoice { get; set; }
```

Likewise, in your mappings, replace this...

```
<many-to-one name="InvoiceID" column="InvoiceID" />
```

... with this:

```
<many-to-one name="Invoice" column="InvoiceID" />
```

### Fix Bag

Also, a bag cannot be many-to-one - it should be one-to-many.  See the [Documentation](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#collections-onetomany).  Replace this...

```
<bag name="InvoiceDetails" access="nosetter.camelcase" inverse ="true" lazy ="false" cascade="all-delete-orphan">
  <key column="InvoiceID"/>
  <many-to-one class="MyProject.Model.InvoiceDetail, MyProject"/>
</bag>
```

... with this:

```
<bag name="InvoiceDetails" access="nosetter.camelcase" inverse ="true" lazy ="false" cascade="all-delete-orphan">
  <key column="InvoiceID"/>
  <one-to-many class="MyProject.Model.InvoiceDetail, MyProject"/>
</bag>
```

### Caution about Lazy=False

One final note: be careful with lazy="false".  If you are intending to improve performance be having NHibernate eagerly fetch those related records, this is not the way to do it.  See http://ayende.com/blog/4573/nhibernate-is-lazy-just-live-with-it for an explanation of why this is a problem.  Refer to http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#performance-fetching for the various way to implement this correctly.

Comment: Thank you, but now I get another error: "MyProject.Mappings.Invoice.hbm.xml(17,8): XML validation error: The element 'bag' in namespace 'urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2' has invalid child element 'many-to-one' in namespace 'urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2'. List of possible elements expected: 'element, one-to-many, many-to-many, composite-element, many-to-any' in namespace 'urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2'." Any thoughts ?

Comment: Oops.  I should have noticed that the first go around.  You've been getting very good error messages.  This error message is exactly right - a bag can't be many-to-one.  It should be one-to-many.  Updating my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for you help, Daniel Schilling. I've got another error about not finding the property or filed invoiceDetails in class Invoice but I changed the name of the private property from _invoiceDetails to invoiceDetails and now it works as expected. I will review the links posted, in almost all parts of application the mapping with lazy ="true" will come handy. Cheers! :D